# Translation - "Adding the key to the list of trusted software vendors failed"

Tags: apt, software-center, translation

I am translating for Ubuntu. This text belongs in ../aptdaemon/enums.py:382 as part of software center, (the settings where it sets the apt sources and where you can add custom sources).

Does anyone know if the "key" means: This one to open doors, the stinking point, the button, the fundamental,... etc.

You know how many meanings...

So what is the best described meaning, because my language Chinese is very specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably referring to the cryptographic key for testing authenticity of the software to download. So I will go with a translation to something that can unlock doors.